# Updating column from a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a result set from a query that returns the plu code and the barcode columns with some conditions. I have a table with one column that i generate some values e.x. `100001`, `100002` etc.

The barcode column for the target table is not null is an empty string. The source and the target table they don't have anything common to join them.

This is what i get.

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 22
> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

This is my query.

```sql
UPDATE ARTICULOSLIN SET CODBARRAS = (SELECT DISTINCT BRC FROM BRC) FROM ARTICULOSLIN ARL
LEFT JOIN ARTICULOS AR ON (ARL.CODARTICULO = AR.CODARTICULO)
WHERE AR.PORPESO = N'F' AND AR.DESCATALOGADO = N'F' AND LEN(ARL.CODBARRAS) != 13
```

Comment: The error *is* telling you the problem (very explicltly); what about the error don't you understand here?

Comment: What join do you want from table `BRC` to table `ARTICULOSLIN`

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. What is wrong is clear, what you are trying to do isn't.

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that you cannot assign multiple values to a single attribute, I believe your subquery returns all values from table BRC.

Comment: I understand that. It returns all the values the BRC table. What should i do i' m asking. I tried with a merge and a cursor to accomplish the update.  Any suggestion....